# How to convert a Python proto-plus Message class into protobuf proto file?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto, google-cloud-sdk

I see that a lot of Google Python SDK code uses the [proto-plus library](https://github.com/googleapis/proto-plus-python) to write protobuf message schemas as a Python class. I was wondering if there is a way to convert this class to a proto file.

ie.

```
import proto

class Composer(proto.Message):
    given_name = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=1)
    family_name = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=2)

class Song(proto.Message):
    composer = proto.Field(Composer, number=1)
    title = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=2)
    lyrics = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=3)
    year = proto.Field(proto.INT32, number=4)
```

and generate a proto file

Answer (score 0):

Proto Plus does not include this functionality.

It should be possible to do this since there's a 1:1 mapping between Proto Plus, Protobuf generated sources and proto files.

But, I suspect it's an anti-pattern. It's not unlike hacking a binary and wanting to regenerate sources.

The source-of-truth for protobuf generated code **is** its proto files.

Google provides Proto Plus to make protoc-generated Python sources more idiomatic.

Presumably Google's build pipeline now includes a generator for Proto Plus sources directly from proto files (this may be part of the SDK or is some adjunct to protoc).

While the Proto Plus docs describe [declaring messages](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messages.html#declaring-messages), I think this is itself an anti-pattern and should not be encouraged as it results in protobuf code without definitive (cross-language) sources(-of-truth).